# How to vertically center only specific cells in a table?

Tags: tables

I have a table as follows:

[image]

I want to vertically align the first column (Map 1, Map 2, Map 3) to center but I could not make it. The code of the table is below:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{cccccccc}
  \toprule        
  & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Map 1}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Map 2} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Map 3} \vspace{1mm}\\
  & & Exp. & Combat & Exp. & Combat & Exp. & Combat \\ \midrule
  Map 1  & Exp.   & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\[0.75ex]
       & Combat & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\ \midrule
  Map 2  & Exp.   & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\[0.75ex]
       & Combat & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\ \midrule
  Map 3  & Exp.   & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\[0.75ex]
       & Combat & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\ \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Are you familiar with the `\multirow` command (provided by a package called `multirow`)?

Comment: Hello @Mico , thank you! Yes, I am familiar with it but all the table became a mess when I  used it. This was the only way I could achieve what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses `\multirow` for the cells in the left-hand column but hopefully avoids letting "all of the table become a mess".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht!]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{} ll cccccc @{}}
  \toprule        
  & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Map 1}  
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Map 2} 
    & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Map 3} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-6} \cmidrule(l){7-8}
  & & Exp.\ & Combat & Exp.\ & Combat & Exp.\ & Combat \\ 
  \midrule
  \multirow{2}{*}{Map 1}  
       & Exp.   & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\
       & Combat & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\ 
  \midrule
  \multirow{2}{*}{Map 2}  
       & Exp.   & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\
       & Combat & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\ 
  \midrule
  \multirow{2}{*}{Map 3}  
       & Exp.   & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\
       & Combat & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\ 
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is perfect! thank you for the effort Mico.